# Как работать с многоуровневыми данными?

Tags: javascript

Например, если у меня есть дома, в которых есть комнаты, в которых есть стулья, как мне организовать структуру данных, чтобы было удобнее с ними работать(удалять добавлять, менять порядок, изменять)?  Самый простой вариант создать массив из объектов домов, в каждом объекте по массиву комнат, в каждой комнате по массиву стульев. Но это ведь жутко неудобно.

Comment: Зависит от конкретных задач, и непонятно, почему вы решили, что это неудобно

Comment: Массив/список или ассоциативный массив (словарь)?

Comment: как вариант - 3 разных массива объектов, у объекта комнат свойство с id дома, у объекта стула свойство с id комнаты, но, как выше сказали, зависит от конкретной задачи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но это ведь жутко неудобно.

Напишите функции-хелперы, вызвав которые Вы сможете обратиться к нужному дому, или комнате, или стулу (*в понятном человеку виде*):

```js
const houses = [{ // многоуровневые данные (дома, квартиры, стулья)
  name: '1/52 А',
  rooms: [{
    name: '10',
    chairs: ['Стул 1', 'Стул 2']
  }]
}, {
  name: '6',
  rooms: [{
    name: '10',
    chairs: ['Стул 1', 'Стул 2', 'Стул 3']
  }, {
    name: '11',
    chairs: ['Стул 1', 'Стул 2', 'Стул 3', 'Стул 4']
  }]
}, {
  name: '3 корп. 4',
  rooms: [{
    name: '55',
    chairs: ['Стул 1']
  }]
}];

console.log('Дом:', getHouseByName('1/52 А'));

console.log('Комната:', getRoomByName('6', '11'));

console.log('Стул:', getChairByName('3 корп. 4', '55', 'Стул 1'));

console.log('Стулья:', getAllChairs('6', '10'));

// функции-хелперы

function getHouseByName(houseName) { // получаем нужный дом
  return houses.find((el) => el.name === houseName);
}

function getRoomByName(houseName, roomName) { // получаем нужную квартиру
  return getHouseByName(houseName).rooms.find((el) => el.name === roomName);
}

function getChairByName(houseName, roomName, chairName) { // получаем нужный стул
  return getAllChairs(houseName, roomName).find((el) => el === chairName);
}

function getAllChairs(houseName, roomName) { // получаем все стулья
  return getRoomByName(houseName, roomName).chairs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

    const ArrayHouse = [
        {
            name: 'house1',
            rooms: [
                {
                    number: 3,
                    chairs: [
                        {
                            color: 'red',
                            height: 10,
                            width: 45
                        },
                        {
                            color: 'red',
                            height: 10,
                            width: 45
                        },
                        {
                            color: 'red',
                            height: 10,
                            width: 45
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    number: 1,
                    chairs: [
                        {
                            color: 'green',
                            height: 10,
                            width: 45
                        },
                        {
                            color: 'black',
                            height: 10,
                            width: 45
                        },
                        {
                            color: 'violet',
                            height: 10,
                            width: 45
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'house2',
            rooms: [
                {
                    number: 3,
                    chairs: [
                        {
                            color: 'red',
                            height: 10,
                            width: 45
                        },
                        {
                            color: 'red',
                            height: 10,
                            width: 45
                        },
                        {
                            color: 'red',
                            height: 10,
                            width: 45
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    number: 1,
                    chairs: [
                        {
                            color: 'green',
                            height: 10,
                            width: 45
                        },
                        {
                            color: 'black',
                            height: 10,
                            width: 45
                        },
                        {
                            color: 'violet',
                            height: 10,
                            width: 45
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    number: 15,
                    chairs: [
                        {
                            color: 'green',
                            height: 102,
                            width: 45
                        },
                        {
                            color: 'white',
                            height: 110,
                            width: 45
                        },
                        {
                            color: 'violet',
                            height: 150,
                            width: 45
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

    class HouseContext {

        constructor() {
            console.log(this.getHouseByName('house1'));
            this.addHouse({
                name: 'addHouse',
                rooms: []
            });
            console.log(ArrayHouse);

            console.log(this.getRoomBuNumber('house2', 1));

            this.addRoom('addHouse', {
                number: 228,
                chairs:[]
            });

            console.log(ArrayHouse);
        }

        getHouseByName(name) {
            return ArrayHouse.find(v => v.name == name);
        }

        addHouse(house) {
            ArrayHouse.push(house);
        }

        getRoomBuNumber(houseName, roomNumber) {
            return ArrayHouse.find(v => v.name == houseName).rooms.find(v => v.number == roomNumber);
        }

        addRoom(houseName, room) {
            ArrayHouse.find(v => v.name == houseName).rooms.push(room);
        }
    }

    new HouseContext();


</script>
```